# Doubt about corollary in Serre's "Local fields"

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In the paragraph "Extension and completion" of Chapter 2 there is the following statement:

**Corollary 1.** The fields $\hat{L_i}$ are the composites of the extensions $\hat{K}$ and $L$ of $K$.

Here $K$ is a field with a discrete valuation $v$ (actually, the result should hold even if the absolute value on $K$ is not induced by a discrete valuation), whose completion I shall denote by $\hat{K}$; $L$ is a finite extension of $K$, and the $\hat{L}_i$ are the completions of $L$ with respect to each different extension $w_i$ of the discrete valuation $v$ on $K$ (or, more generally, the completions with respect to the absolute values $|\cdot|_1,\dots,|\cdot|_r$ that extend the absolute value on $K$).

I am convinced that this is true, but I fail to see exactly why: suppose, in the separable case, that $L=K(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in L$ with minimal polynomial $\mu\in K[x]$; if $\mu=\mu_1\dots\mu_r$ is its factorization on $\hat{K}[x]$, then one could explicitly describe each $\hat{L_i}$ as the quotient $\hat{K}[x]/(\mu_i(x))$. In particular, the $\hat{L}_i$ have *a priori* different degrees over $\hat{K}$, while $L\hat{K}$ is uniquely determined as a field, hence it has its own fixed degree, regardless of the absolute value defined on it.

Is there something, possibly quite trivial, that I am missing? I think it has to do with the nature of the isomorphism $L\otimes_{K}\hat{K}\rightarrow\prod_i\hat{L}_i$.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more context for the notations you are using. What are $L$, $K$, $\hat{K}$, $\widehat{L_i}$? Also, please don't give a page number unless you specify exactly what edition of the book you are using.

Comment: Done. Please tell me if more details are needed.

Comment: $L\hat{K}$ is ambiguous and misleading. Yes $\hat{L}_i = \hat{K}(\alpha_i)$ for each root of $\alpha$'s $K$-minimal polynomial in an algebraic closure of $\hat{K}$. Once you are given $\hat{L}_i$ then there is an embedding $\rho_i:L\to \hat{L}_i$ such that $\hat{L}_i=\rho_i(L)\hat{K}$.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Thank you!